# iPhone App Size Compatibility

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.6

I'm making an iPhone app, and I'm using storyboard for the majority of the UI. I'm using xCode 4.6 for iOS 6.

**Is there a way to make the app work for both iphone4 size and iphone5 sizes?**

When I run the app on the iPhone 4 simulator it doesn't look like it's supposed to - the UI elements don't look like they do on the storyboard (which I'm assuming uses the iPhone5 size).

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically access the height of the view and the device, and then make adjustments based on those values.  Alternatively, you could use iOS 6's constraints to set a margin between the bottom of the device or between other elements.

To achieve the former, just access the height property of the view:

```
CGFloat height = [[self view] frame].size.height;
```

You can also get the height of the device's screen like so:

```
CGFloat deviceHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
deviceHeight -= 20; // remove the tab bar
deviceHeight -= 44; // remove height for a navigation bar?
```

Now imagine adjust your view's origin based on this value.  You can make it hug the bottom of the device, no matter which one you're on.

```
[aView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, deviceHeight - 10 - 100, 300, 100)];
```

If you're unable to adjust the layout of the elements, consider using a scroll view as well.  Just set the frame using the techniques above, and then set the content size.  On smaller devices, you'll be able to scroll to see more content whereas on larger devices, it will all be right there.